# Parse::UserCannotBeAlteredWithoutSessionError

Tags: android, parse-platform

The issue started when I updated Parse SDK to Parse 1.9.4. I get this error when I try to update any object with a user object property / pointer in it.

I am using anonymous user and I am aware of the migration of session tokens.

I did follow the guide by adding ParseUser.enableRevocableSessionInBackground();

I still get the error. I even tried turning on and tuning off the revoke session setting in the parse console. Nothing works.

It works when I clear the cache and reinstall the app, but as soon as you exit the app, for some reason the tokens are removed.

Do I have to do anything else ?
Any Help will be appreciated.

Comment: could you post some code